# IE8 reboots machine when updating Activex controls

Tags: internet-explorer, activex, restart

IE8 prompts a machine restart whenever there is an update in the activex control. Is this a known bug with IE8? Its doesn't happen in IE9, is there any documentation on this or a workaround solution?

Comment: How is this programming related?

Answer (score 0):

IE8 most likely does not prompt the machine restart; the installer service prompts the machine restart. IE9 may simply deal with the open files differently.

How are you updating the control? Are you installing the new one as a different filename? (if the file is in use then you can't replace it without something replacing it; this would cause an installer to want to restart your computer)

Also, if you are installing a new file but the old file is in use many installers will flag that file to be deleted at the next restart, and that will generally cause the installer to prompt you to restart your computer.

If you're using an MSI installer there is a restartmanager that you can disable manually if you wish; with WiX I believe the command is `<Property Id="MSIRESTARTMANAGERCONTROL" Value="Disable" />`

Anyway, maybe that'll give you some ideas to look at.